# java.lang.NullPointerException error when coping files/directory depending on path used for source and destination

Tags: java, swing, io

When copying files I'm experiencing a NullPointerException depending on what path I'm using as a source and destination.  One version of source and dest gives a successful copy and another version errors out.

I'm trying to understand why the difference in path is causing an error.

This works and creates directory's and files.

```
String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\inkjet\\ABC"; 
String destPath = "C:\\inkjet\\";
```

This errors out and gives a NullPointerException.

```
String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\inkjet\\ABC"; 
String destPath = "C:\\inkjet\\ABC";
```

The difference is the addition of ABC on the destination path.

```
public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {

   private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

   public DetailsPanel() {

      Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
      size.width = 250;
      setPreferredSize(size);

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Inkjet files to copy"));

      JLabel clientLabel = new JLabel("Client acronym: ");
      JLabel jobLabel = new JLabel("Job number: ");

      final JTextField clientField = new JTextField(10);
      final JTextField jobField = new JTextField(10);

      JButton addBtn = new JButton("Copy");

      addBtn.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
               String client = clientField.getText();           
               clientField.setText("");                 

               String job = jobField.getText();
               jobField.setText("");                

               String text = client + ": " + job + "\n";

               try {
                  fileCopy(client, job);
               } catch (IOException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
               }

            }

         //*****************************************test

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void fileCopy(String nClient, String nJob) throws IOException {

               //String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\FileTest\\" + nClient + "\\" + nJob; 
               //String destPath = "C:\\MB\\FileTest\\" + nClient + "\\" + nJob;


               //this works
               //String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\inkjet\\ABC"; 
               //String destPath = "C:\\inkjet\\";

              //this doesn't work
               String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\inkjet\\ABC"; 
               String destPath = "C:\\inkjet\\ABC";


               fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "Source path:  " + sourcePath + "\n"));
               fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "Destination path:  " + destPath + "\n"));

               File source = new File(sourcePath);  
               File dest = new File(destPath);  

               //Call to method copyUsingStream
               long start = System.nanoTime(); //start recording how much time the copy takes.
               copyUsingStream(source, dest);  //method to copy the directory/files.

               fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "Time taken to copy the file(s): "+(System.nanoTime() -start) + " nanoseconds" + "\n"));

            }

            /**
               The copyUsingStream method is a recursive method to copy folders and files from one location to another.
            */

            private void copyUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {   

               if (!source.isDirectory()){ 
                  // If source is a file -> copy it to the new folder
                  InputStream inStream = null;
                  OutputStream outStream = null;
                  try {
                     inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
                     outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                     int length;

                     while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                     }
                  } finally {
                     inStream.close();
                     outStream.close();

                     fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "File copied from " + source + " to " + dest + " successfully" + "\n"));
                  } 


               } else {

                  //If a directory -> create the directory inside the new destination
                  //List all contents


                  if (!dest.exists()) {
                     dest.mkdir();

                     fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "Directory copied from " + source + " to " + dest + " successfully" + "\n"));


                  }


                  String folder_contents[] = source.list();

                  for (String file : folder_contents) {

                     File srcFile = new File(source, file);
                     File destFile = new File(dest, file);

                     copyUsingStream(srcFile, destFile);

                  }

               }

            } //end method copyUsingStream          



         //*****************************************test


         });

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //// First column //////////////////////////////////////

      gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
      gc.weightx = 0.5;
      gc.weighty = 0.5;

      gc.gridx = 0;
      gc.gridy = 0;

      add(clientLabel, gc);

      gc.gridx = 0;
      gc.gridy = 1;
      add(jobLabel, gc);

    //// second column /////////////////////////////////////

      gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
      gc.gridx = 1;
      gc.gridy = 0;
      add(clientField, gc);

      gc.gridx = 1;
      gc.gridy = 1;
      add(jobField, gc);

    //// final row /////////////////////////////////////////
      gc.weighty = 10;

      gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
      gc.gridx = 1;
      gc.gridy = 2;
      add(addBtn, gc);

   }

   public void fireDetailEvent(DetailEvent event) {
      Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

      for(int i=0; i < listeners.length; i += 2) {
         if(listeners[i] == DetailListener.class) {
            ((DetailListener)listeners[i+1]).detailEventOccurred(event);
         }
      }
   }

   public void addDetailListener(DetailListener listener) {
      listenerList.add(DetailListener.class, listener);
   }

   public void removeDetailListener(DetailListener listener) {
      listenerList.remove(DetailListener.class, listener);
   }

}
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at DetailsPanel$1.copyUsingStream(DetailsPanel.java:125)    at
>   DetailsPanel$1.copyUsingStream(DetailsPanel.java:153)     at
>   DetailsPanel$1.copyUsingStream(DetailsPanel.java:153)     at
>   DetailsPanel$1.fileCopy(DetailsPanel.java:98)     at
>   DetailsPanel$1.actionPerformed(DetailsPanel.java:52)  at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

The error on line 125 is the outStream.close(); line.

```
          } finally {
             inStream.close();
             outStream.close();

             fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "File copied from " + source + " to " + dest + " successfully" + "\n"));
          } 


       } else {
```

Comment: Could you point out where exactly is line 125 in your code? Because it's there where we have to start search for the problem.

Comment: It's:outStream.close();

Comment: Can you check the value of outStream when you create it? (= new FileOutputStream(dest);) it's null?

Comment: It may be a silly question, but have you checked if you actually have permissions over the folder `C:\\inkjet\\ABC`. Also, check if it works like this `C:\\inkjet\\ABC\\ `

Comment: You get the NPE when there is an exception because the streams are still null. Use a try-with-resources instead.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you need to identify the stream is null or not before you close it.

```
if(inStream != null ) inStream.close();
if(outStream != null ) outStream.close();
```

And add the catch to see what happened.

```
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
                     inStream.close();
                     outStream.close();

                     fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, "File copied from " + source + " to " + dest + " successfully" + "\n"));
                  }
```